# Expandable CardView

Tags: xml, material-design, android-cardview, expandable

I have CardViews which contain TextViews with large amount of Text and I want to make them expandable so that the content is just shown, when its needed. For example:

Variety 1
[image]

Variety 2
[image]

Any advise?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to have a regular card with different ViewGroups. You can toggle the visibility of those ViewGroups (VISIBLE or INVISIBLE/GONE) when the user click the "expand/collapse" button.

[You can try to animate those changes](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/animation/layout.html) but it can cause you some problems if your CardView is withing a recyclerView (you'll need probably more than that one-liner in the xml to make the animations work well).

Comment: I'll try that when I'm home. Thank you. Luckily enough I didn't put my cards into a recyclerView, instead of it I inserted them one by one into my nestedScrollView because I did not know how to put a RecyclerView into a NestedScrollView.